# Maven: How do I use JMetro styling with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I wanted to use JMetro styling in my Maven project, but whatever I do, Maven gives me the same error. I am using `javafx-archetype-simple` from `org.openjfx`, and I tried using JMetro by adding it as a dependency in my `pom.xml`, and downloading it from JCenter by adding the `.settings.xml` to `~/.m2/`. Whenever I tried to do `mvn javafx:run` after `mvn clean`, I always get this error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------< io.colocasian.calc:ore-no-calculator >----------------
[INFO] Building ore-no-calculator 1.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.4:run (default-cli) > process-classes @ ore-no-calculator >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ ore-no-calculator ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/rishvic/Documents/Java/ore-no-calculator/src/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ ore-no-calculator ---
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from jmetro-11.6.5.pom: zip END header not found
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /home/rishvic/Documents/Java/ore-no-calculator/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/rishvic/Documents/Java/ore-no-calculator/src/main/java/io/colocasian/calc/App.java:[17,22] package jfxtras.styles does not exist
[ERROR] /home/rishvic/Documents/Java/ore-no-calculator/src/main/java/io/colocasian/calc/App.java:[35,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Style
  location: class io.colocasian.calc.App
[ERROR] /home/rishvic/Documents/Java/ore-no-calculator/src/main/java/io/colocasian/calc/App.java:[35,40] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Style
  location: class io.colocasian.calc.App
[ERROR] /home/rishvic/Documents/Java/ore-no-calculator/src/main/java/io/colocasian/calc/App.java:[377,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class JMetro
  location: class io.colocasian.calc.App
[INFO] 4 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.443 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-31T21:46:28+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project ore-no-calculator: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/rishvic/Documents/Java/ore-no-calculator/src/main/java/io/colocasian/calc/App.java:[17,22] package jfxtras.styles does not exist
[ERROR] /home/rishvic/Documents/Java/ore-no-calculator/src/main/java/io/colocasian/calc/App.java:[35,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Style
[ERROR]   location: class io.colocasian.calc.App
[ERROR] /home/rishvic/Documents/Java/ore-no-calculator/src/main/java/io/colocasian/calc/App.java:[35,40] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable Style
[ERROR]   location: class io.colocasian.calc.App
[ERROR] /home/rishvic/Documents/Java/ore-no-calculator/src/main/java/io/colocasian/calc/App.java:[377,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class JMetro
[ERROR]   location: class io.colocasian.calc.App
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Link to [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Colocasian/67da35c1a00ca802a0ffe919d62d1e3e) containing my edited `pom.xml`, `settings.xml` and `App.java` which I used to try to use JMetro in my project. Source code (without JMetro, which actually runs with `mvn clean javafx:run`) [linked here](https://github.com/Colocasian/legacy-ore-no-calculator).

Output of `java -version`:

```
openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.6+10, mixed mode)
```

Output of `mvn --version`:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (NON-CANONICAL_2019-11-27T20:26:29Z_root)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 11.0.6, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.4.15-2-manjaro", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

PS: I am really new to using Maven, I would really appreciate some advice regarding using Maven, in general, and also using JavaFX on it. Originally, posted this question on [Github Issues](https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras-styles/issues/139#issue-558235325), on the [JFXtras Styles](https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras-styles) Git repo, but it wasn't really an issue with JMetro itself, so posted this question here.

**Extra info**: I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but I am still adding it as reference. When I added JMetro 11.6.7 as a dependency and reran `mvn clean javafx:run`, while downloading, it gave me these warnings,

```
...
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from jmetro-11.6.7.pom: zip END header not found
...
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from jmetro-11.6.7.pom: Only outputDirectories and jars are accepted on the path
[WARNING] Some dependencies encountered issues while attempting to be resolved as modules and will not be included in the classpath; you can change this behavior via the  'includePathExceptionsInClasspath' configuration parameter.
```

Comment: I think your import is wrong. Maybe you could try a star import with `import jfxtras.styles.jmetro.*;`.

Comment: I tried it. Didn't work.

Comment: I'm not so sure that the extra repository is needed, JMetro seems to be in Maven central. In any case you never need or should edit your settings.xml, you can declare any extra repository that a project needs directly in the pom itself. http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories

Comment: I tried running without adding the `settings.xml` to my `~/.m2/` folder, but it couldn't find the dependency on Maven Central. It seems the creator forgot to add it to Maven Central repo (link here: https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras-styles/issues/139#issuecomment-580965567). And I don't think that should have to do anything to this specific issue.

Comment: @A-Warm-Jicama it would if the repo is not functioning correctly and gives you a non-functional pom.

Answer (score 2):

The official Maven repo of JMetro didn't work for me as well. I resorted to downloading the JMetro jar from GitHub, adding it manually to Maven, and then use it in my JavaFX apps.

Here's what I did to make JMetro play nice with Maven:

1. Download the official JMetro jar from [GitHub](https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras-styles/)
2. Add the downloaded jar to the local Maven repo:

   ```
   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=jmetro-11.6.15.jar -DgroupId=com.jfxtras -DartifactId=jmetro -Dversion=11.6.15
   ```
3. Add it to the project's `pom.xml` as a dependency:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.jfxtras</groupId>
       <artifactId>jmetro</artifactId>
       <version>11.6.15</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
4. For modular projects, declare it in project's `module-info.java`:

   ```
   module <ModuleName> {
       ...
       requires org.jfxtras.styles.jmetro;
       ...
   }
   ```

Now JMetro can be used normally.